# How to connect ioredis to google cloud function?

Tags: redis, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, ioredis

I am currently running some Google Cloud functions (in typescript) that require a connection to a Redis instance in order to `LPUSH` into the queue (on other instances, I am using Redis as a queue worker).
Everything is fine, except I am getting a huge number of `ECONNECTRESET` and `ECONNECTIMEOUT` related errors despite everything working properly.

The following code can execute successfully on the cloud function but still, I am seeing constant errors thrown related to the connection to the Redis.

I think it is somehow related to how I am importing my `client- ioredis`. I have `utils/index.ts`, `utils/redis.js` and inside the `redis.js` I have:

```
const Redis = require('ioredis'); 
module.exports = new Redis(6380, 'MYCACHE.redis.cache.windows.net', { tls: true, password: 'PASS' });
```

Then I am importing this in my `utils/index.ts` like so: *code missing*

And exporting some aysnc function like: *code missing*

When executing in the `GCF` environment, I get the # of expected results in `results.length` and I see (by monitoring the Redis internally) this list was pushed as expected to the queue.

Nevertheless, these errors continue to appear incessantly.

```
ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: read ECONNRESET at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11) at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:628:25)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! I've improved your question's formatting. I also noticed that you're referring to two pieces of code you forgot to add (I've replaced them with *code missing*). Could you please edit your question and add the missing parts?

Comment: Seems to be duplicated by: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758506/google-cloud-functions-redis-econnreset