# Google Cloud Functions & Redis: ECONNRESET

Tags: redis, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, connection-pooling, ioredis

Does anyone know why I continually get this error from cloud functions (google cloud functions) when using ioredis module?

> [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: read ECONNRESET at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11) at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:628:25)

[error log sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsJSw.png)
The error never stops. It doesn't affect normal operation (meaning, I can perform all desired operaitons just fine with ioredis module & my redis).  Its incredibly obnoxious and makes it impossible to debug cloud function performance.

Notes:
Using redis cache on Microsoft Azure (though I've tried self-managed redis on google compute as well), premium tier.

I suspect this must have something to do with how I am instantiating the redis/importing it. I am using it in only one file, utils/index.ts, and am intantiating it like so:

```
const redis = new Redis(6380, 'myredis.redis.cache.windows.net', { tls: true as any, password: 'azuresucks=' });
```

I've tried no-TLS, creating new caches, and pretty much everything else I can think of. Anyone with insight into ioredis and its compatibility with cloud functions, please help!m Note: I actually have tried using node_redis vs. ioredis- still having this issue.

Edit: Full Sample code from `utils/index.ts`
https://gist.github.com/nicoandmee/c38d2b014b4377a4f386a0a0ae9a85e5
And here is my `index.ts' which is my entry point (where I am exporting the actual firebase functions).
https://gist.github.com/nicoandmee/6e1d7d319effa1f23141b7148e3459c7

Here's an example of what I mean when I say it doesn't affect normal operation. Here my function executed successfully, but the error is still popping up constantly, seconds after. My code runs fine, but I can barely tell because of all this spam from the ECONNRESET being thrown. Maybe there is a way to just suppress this error / handle it? Because its not affecting my code otherwise.
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izH92.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire, minimal Cloud Function that reproduces the problem, not just a single line.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry about that, just added specific example

Comment: Please put your entire, minimal code directly in the question rather than linking out to some other resource.

Comment: Please make your question self contained without requiring external links. Tomorrow those links may be non-existent, chage, break, etc which makes your question / answers worthless for future readers.